# PostgreSQL Entity framework webapi arrays not supporting

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

we have character varying array in postgreSQL and using entity framework web api to retrieve the columns. but entity framework throws `"The specified type member 'xxx' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported"` when I declare the field as `string[]`. We also tried type as `List<string>`.

how to map array columns from postgres in entity framework?

Comment: Where is the `string[]` code? Is that the definition of the field on the model/class? If so, why not just use `string`?